# Bootstrap - Set Logo outside the navbar div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In this example site: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

I want a navbar like the one they have on the top, but where "project name" is I want a logo that has a height larger than the other part of the navbar, but I want the logo to overhang out the bottom, not having the div resize to fit the bigger height of the logo.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by using `absolute` positioning for your logo element. This takes it out of the normal page flow and allows you to position it more precisely.

```
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  // Use your own values for anything below this line.
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

For this to work you need to make sure that the container element is positioned to `relative`, in this case the `navbar` div. The `z-index` ensures that the logo is displayed on top of the navbar.

```
<div class="nav navbar">
  <a class="logo">
    My Logo
  </a>
</div>
```